# "Sync" system images

Tags: sync

I have two machines one with exclusive Ubuntu, and other with Ubuntu + windows. 
My dotfiles are synced up using an off-premise vcs repository, and same for my projects.

However, I'd like my system images to be in sync too, at some level. For example, if I install a software on a machine, it should be somehow easier to install the same software on the other machine. Or if I change my sshd settings, then similar. I am okay if this causes the two computers to end up identical, although I'd prefer the ability to have some machine specific settings too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/) ? I think it can perform something like automatically (Scheduled) create a system image to a NAS (File Server).

I have experience in making two PCs completely identical with Macrium Reflect. But your case is a far more advanced one.